System locks up trying to install latest kernel
During the update, my system was completely locked up.
linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
I have tried to recover, but the lock-up happens each time.
I am wondering how this can be corrected.

The lock up happens when? The exact thing you are doing when this occurs. What have you done to try and recover?
